# Setting up AndroidViewClient on Windows 8 gives Raise AttributeError

Tags: python, androidviewclient

I have downloaded the .zip from https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient which is version 5.1.1 
. 
I have added ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME=/path/to/AndroidViewClient
and PYTHONPATH=/path/to/AndroidViewClient/src .

Now when i run python test-connect-to-device.py , I am getting raise AttributeError

[image]

Comment: You are using a very old **AndroidViewClient** version and you should use a newer one, latest is **9.2.1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to using Python 3 to run code that will only work in Python 2.  You will have to install Python 2 and run your script using Python 2 to get around this.

For example, the code

```
name = "blah"
raise AttributeError, name
```

[runs and raises an AttributeError on Python 2](https://ideone.com/4BOESM) but [raises a SyntaxError and fails to compile on Python 3](https://ideone.com/6ccbVc).